# Add active class dynamically to menu and its submenu using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I create an application in `asp.net mvc`.
This is a code of HTML that I created for navigation bar.

```
<div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse">          
            <div class="leftside-navigation">
                <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="active">
                            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                            <span>Dashboard</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="dcjq-parent">
                            <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
                            <span>Masters</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("BankDetails","BankDetailMasters")">Bank</a></li>
                            <li class="sub-menu">
                                <a href="javascript:;">
                                    <span>Calibration</span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="sub">
                                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("CalibrationCycleTypeDetails","CalibrationCycleType")">Cycle Type</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("CalibrationStatusDetails", "CalibrationStatus")">Status</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("CompanyDetail","CompanyDetails")">Company</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("CurrencyDetail","Currency")">Currency</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("CustomerDetail","Customer")">Customer</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("DepartmentDetail","Department")">Department</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("EmployeeDetail","Employee")">Employee</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("IndustryTypeDetail", "IndustryType")">Industry Type</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("ShippingAgentDetail", "ShippingAgent")">Shipping Agent</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("StateDetail", "State")">State</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("SupplierDetail", "Supplier")">Supplier</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("TransporterDetail", "Transporter")">Transporter</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("UnitDetails", "Unit")">Unit</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Now i want to add "active" class in li's a tag.

when it has sub menu than add `"dcjq-parent"` & `"active"` in li's a.
and add "active" class in its li's a tag

here is my "dcjq-parent" class

```
ul.sidebar-menu li a.active, ul.sidebar-menu li a:hover, ul.sidebar-menu li a:focus {
background: #28282e;
color: #1FB5AD;
display: block;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

}

here is my jaquery

```
$('#sidebar .leftside-navigation > ul li ul.sub li').click(function (e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.addClass('active');
            $this.find('.dcjq-parent').addClass('active');
});
```

Hope someone will help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Where is "dcjq-parent" class.

Comment: "dcjq-parent" is a custom class for format font color

Comment: when any li has sub menu than "dcjq-parent" class add to that li's a tag

Comment: You must show the code with this class because you are using `find`.

Comment: ok i update in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code,

In your code you are going to call $(this) means li of your '.sub' class which does not contain '.dcjq-parent' so jauery couldn't find it and your result less.
So to access your parent you need a parent() of jauery to go to thru the hierarchy.

```js
$(".sub li").click(function(){
$(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.dcjq-parent').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse">          
    <div class="leftside-navigation">
     <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
      <li>
       <a href="#" class="active">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
        <span>Dashboard</span>
       </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-menu">
       <a href="javascript:;" class="dcjq-parent">
        <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
        <span>Masters</span>
       </a>
       <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">Bank</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu">
         <a href="javascript:;">
          <span>Calibration</span>
         </a>
         <ul class="sub">
          <li><a href="#">Cycle Type</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Status</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Currency</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Customer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Department</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Employee</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Industry Type</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shipping Agent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">State</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Supplier</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Transporter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Unit</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: i think its working but the problem is when page is reload it is not work..@Ketan_Hirapara

Comment: so for the same you have to handle in each page like when you click on  "bank" then you have to add js on bank page or cshtml page with same jquery. on each sub pages that should how you can maintain active class on the same page as well as the hierarchic parent note active class.

Comment: for example add id to each li for bank li its id=bank $(function(){$("#bank").addClass('active');
            $("#bank").parent().parent().find('.dcjq-parent').addClass('active'); });

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code with jQuery it is working properly**

```
$(function () {
        setNavigation();
    });

    function setNavigation() {
        var path = window.location.pathname;
        path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
        path = decodeURIComponent(path);

        $("#sidemenu .nav-item .nav-link").each(function () {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
                $(this).closest('a').addClass('active');
            }
        });

        $("#sidemenu .nav-item ul li a").each(function () {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
                $(this).closest('a').addClass('active');
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.nav-content').addClass('show');
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.nav-link').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
```

```
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="javascript:;">Parent</a>
            <ul class="nav-content collapse">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child-1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child-2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child-3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
  
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've picked you up wrong bit dcjq-parent doesn't exist in your markup?

This should work

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lvhx5bm/2/

```
$('ul.sub li').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('active').addClass('dcjq-parent');
    $('.dcjq-parent.active > a').addClass('active');
```

});

Comment: The jsFiddle is. It adds a class to the li as well as the a tag within it.

Comment: I just updated the jsfiddle with a little css, maybe that will make it clearer for you. I'm not sure if it's the solution you need but on li click it adds active and .dcjq-parent to the li then also active to the a tag

Comment: OK, I don't understand then, sorry. Good luck!